# How to create a delivery URL that listens to a webhook on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a 2 websites, lets say SITE1 & SITE2

both running woo-commerce.

SITE1 receives orders, for every completed order on SITE1 i have to send an initiation to SITE2 with order information.

I created an webhook on SITE1 that posts information on SITE2 on every order creation

https://site2.com/webhook/

This above URL on SITE2 is a simple PHP file that accepts whatever that is posted to the URL.

But anything posted to that URL gets a 403 Forbidden by default.

How to create an URL that accepts woocommerce webhook post request that trigger a function?

Is there any inbuilt function for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a plugin like this...or adding to your functions in your theme:

```
// make a function that loads before anything on wordpress loads
add_action('init','webhook_super_star');

// in the function look for a unique server related URI
// I personally like to check against a GET variable

function webhook_super_star() {
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/webhook' ||
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/webhook/') {
        //Do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

That's my guess with the information provided.

Have a nice day.